# Jump to bottom of context menu in PhpStorm

Tags: macos, phpstorm

With context menus in PhpStorm, similar to the one below, I am unable to hit the up arrow to jump to the bottom of the menu. However I can do this on my other mac. I have not found any information around the web regarding this annoyance or whether it applies directly to PhpStorm (any version) or the OS (Mojave) in general. Any ideas on how I can enable this behavior?

[image: context menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have disabled that option accidentally:

`Settings/Prefrences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Cyclic scrolling in list`

[image]

Comment: Are you serious. How in the world did I not see that. Thank you so much for helping me find it!!